# Custom action bar leaves black space on the left android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have created a custom action bar

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Choose"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The java code

```
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    bar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_layout);
```

The screenshot

[image: SCREENSHOT]

As you can see it leaves a mall black space to the top left of the screen. I don't want it. I want it to be pure white.

What needs to be done to achieve this.

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
    new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

Comment: @WISHY: This is a more proper solution instead of applying white color as a patch..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout

Answer (score 1):

Try to call setDisplayShowHomeEnabled() with false.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29